# Machine learning: inferring parents from child data

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

In producing SCADA systems, we get large lists of signals.

The signals can be a couple of thousands and all have verbal descriptions such as:

```
Diesel Generator 1 Fuel Pressure
Diesel Generator 1 Oil Pressure
Diesel Generator 2 Fuel Pressure
Diesel Generator 2 Oil Pressure
```

There are no guarantees how much of the phrase (or what part) covers the Parent (Diesel generator 1) and what is the specific signal detail. These lists are perused by humans to implement them.

In Power Management System, the entities "DG1"and "DG2" (DG = Diesel generator) are sort of singletons. They are pre-known entities that are either present or not present. So it is possible to look for them and it makes sense that the resulting algorithm will be able to positively identify them.

But in other subsystems, such as Cargo Management, we do not know upfront how many pumps, valves and sensors we have. Their naming is not consistent or interesting.

We have been in this business for a long time and we have hundreds of delivered vessels where a human has already created a system from such a signal list. I can reverse engineer existing vessels and tell the algorithm what signal descriptions turned out to be related.
However, I'm not sure how this would be represented in the learning data, though. If I e.g introduce a column like this

```
Separator 1 Inlet pump pressure  "Inl1Pmp"
Sep1 Inlet Pmp flow              "Inl1Pmp"
Sep1 Inlet Pmp Emgcy Stop        "Inl1Pmp"
Sep1 Outlet Pmp flow             "Out1Pmp"
```

The challenge here is that I want to signify that the top three signals were acting on the **same main equipment**, that it was a **pump** in the **Process** subsystem. It's not as interesting to find that it was "Inl1Pmp" specifically because the next project will have similar sounding signals, but with a completely different name for the pump itself.
All of these things I can tell the learning data if there is some good way to represent it in the learning data. Being a *Pump* and being a part of *Processing* are just two columns in the learning data, but again the really interesting bit is to reduce thousands of signals automatically grouped into hundreds of onboard equipment.

I have presented this problem in casual conversation to a couple of machine learning experts. One speculated that this may be a **clustering** problem.

My questions:

- How do I represent signal affiliation in learning data without attaching an identity to it?
- What sort of machine learning problem is this? Are there specific topics I should look into?
- Are there online tools where I can direct the data in csv/xml/json form?

I don't know if this was clear. When trying to explain the problem to laymen, I try to use an example of a picture of an unknown number of people and that you should, based on a list of facts about the individuals determine how many individuals are in the picture without knowing if a person is referred to as "John" or "The clown", "The guy with makeup".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the layman explanation, the technical part is a bit hard to follow.

As far as I understand, ultimately the goal would be to be able to process these long lists of descriptions and automatically extract a short standardized string for each element in the list.

The main choice to make is between supervised classification or unsupervised clustering:

- In classification the model learns to associate features (for instance "does the description contains the word 'Inlet'?") with output labels (classes). The classes are predefined and the model needs to be trained on some annotated data (hence 'supervised').
- In clustering the model groups instances (descriptions represented by their features) by their similarity. There is no label as output.

In your scenario it seems to me that you need the output to represent specific characteristics known in advance, so this belongs to supervised classification, more precisely text classification. You would need a representative sample as training data: many descriptions with their expected label/class. A simple text classification system would represent the words in the description as features over the whole vocabulary (across all descriptions), then during training the model would find which words are good indicators of which label/class. After training the model can be applied to any new description to predict its label/class.

Text classification is very common, you can find a lot of material/libraries online, maybe even some web or GUI software to do the whole thing but I don't know any.

You could try clustering but my guess is that it won't work the way you want, because it's meant for cases where one doesn't expect any particular categories.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. How would you represent clustering in the learning data? How do I tell the system "you are supposed to figure out that these four data points are related and that those other two are related".

Comment: @Tormod this is precisely why I'd recommend supervised learning in this case, unsupervised is meant for cases where there's no expectation about the resulting clusters. But to answer your question, in both supervised and unsupervised the instances are represented with features, for examples boolean features indicating whether a particular word belongs to the description. So to some extent clustering can be tweaked by selecting the features which are relevant to the goal, for instance include "inlet" and  "outlet" but exclude "flow".

Comment: I'm sorry for being slow, but I still don't get it. Imagine I have a thousand statements relating to one hundred individuals. How do I represent the desired clustering in the learning data? How do I tell the learning algorithm that lines 2,242,155,152 and 196 were referring to the same person? I don't want to label or identify the person because I want the algorithm not be good at identifying the person, merely clustering the statements that refer to the same person.

Comment: Let me say again that I doubt the problem that you're describing is suitable for clustering, which is unsupervised learning. By definition there is no "supervision", which means that the algorithm is *not* told what to find (and is unlikely to find exactly what is "expected"). Now in the last case that you describe one would represent the statements by the words they contain (similar to what I said in my previous comment), then the clustering algorithm would try to group statements by calculating a distance between the sets of words. A low distance means that the statements are quite ...

Comment: ... similar so they are likely to belong to the same cluster, and conversely. However what these clusters would reveal is not necessarily the individuals: it's likely that the same individual would tend to use similar vocabulary but not always, it's also likely that the clusters would match similar topics by different persons, etc. Btw there's a lot of work in automatic stylometry about this kind of question, it's a complex problem which cannot be solved completely in general.